# How can I fix "/etc/cron.daily/logrotate: gzip: stdin: file size changed while zipping"?

Tags: email, logrotate

in last days i get daily mail from cron's logrotate task:

> /etc/cron.daily/logrotate:
>
> gzip: stdin: file size changed while zipping

How can I fix it?

Thanks,
Gian Marco.

Comment: See [here](http://superuser.com/questions/630782/)

Answer (score 27):

Here's [a blog post in French](http://blog.claude.duvergier.fr/2013/09/logrotate-gzip-stdin-file-size-changed-while-zipping/) which gives a solution.

In English, you can read [this bug report](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=718703).

To summarise:

1. First you have to add the `--verbose` option in the script `/etc/cron.daily/logrotate` to have more information the next time it runs to identify which rotation log cause the problem.

   ```
   #!/bin/sh

   test -x /usr/sbin/logrotate || exit 0
   /usr/sbin/logrotate --verbose /etc/logrotate.conf`
   ```
2. Next you have to add the `delaycompress` option in logrotate configuration.

   Like exemple, I add the nginx's logrotate configiguration in /etc/logrotate.d/nginx:

   ```
   /var/log/nginx/*.log {
       daily
       missingok
       rotate 14
       compress
       delaycompress
       notifempty
       create 0640 www-data adm
       sharedscripts
       ...
   }
   ```

Comment: Can you run the logrotate straight away or do you have to wait for it to run again? How do you add delaycompress to the logrotate configuration? Can you give an example?

Comment: @LanceHolland you can run it again with: /usr/sbin/logrotate /etc/logrotate.conf

However, depending on your logrotate settings (frequency, minsize, etc), the conditions may not be sufficient to cause the gzip issue. I think it is best to add verbose and then let it run as per the daily schedule.

Comment: `delaycompress` will only help you in certain cases. See my answer.

Answer (score 5):

`upstart` will close (and reopen) its log file when [it notices that the file is deleted](https://paperairoplane.net/?p=725). However, if you look at [what gzip does](https://gist.github.com/JensRantil/2bd9fa234c84afa73e1fb3422c63aab0), you see that it doesn't delete the file until after it's one writing the output file. That means that there always is a race condition where log lines might be lost for lines logs being written `gzipping`.

You can disable the warning using `gzip --quiet`, but really that doesn't hide the fact that you might still loose log lines.

This means that `delaycompress` is not a generic fix to this. It's a specific fix to a specific problem.

The real solution for this is probably a combination of `delaycompress` and being able to send a signal to the process. It will make the race condition go away in practise (unless you rotate multiple times per second :) ).